# Error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) in package declaration section

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning java on my own and i'm stuck with this error. i have been trying to do a sample program by creating a package. Please help me to solve me the error. Code is given below:-

```
package pack;
class A
{
    public void fun()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World...!!!");
    }
}

import pack.A;
public class PackageExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        A a=new A();
        a.fun();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these classes in two different files? If so, you need a package declaration on the second class (PackageExample) because right now it doesn't belong to a package. Also, your class A is not public, so classes outside the `pack` package will not be able to access it.

Comment: Are the two classes in same file or different files?

Comment: I don't think you have spent enough time trying to figure this out yourself, you haven't said  what you have tried, and there are plenty of examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import statements need to be at the top (below your package declaration). But in your case you don't even need the import statement because both classes are in the same file, so you can just delete `import pack.A`.

Comment: I did get the error corrected following your answer. Actually, I wanted to import the method from the package, with package and main program in different files. After getting a help from eclipse itself, I moved the main program to default package section and saved the package declaration separately. Now, the main program is error-free after adding import statement.